# Wicket radio group client side validation

Tags: validation, wicket

I have gender radio group (male female) which I want to validate if no value got picked by the client writing the js itself is not a problem .

How to attach it to wicket component is the problem .

Answer (score 0):

As with all the components in Wicket, you can add a behavior to it.
See the [javadocs](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#add%28org.apache.wicket.behavior.Behavior...%29).